# Diagonal matrix basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $e_1,e_2,e_3$ be basis of V and $\phi$ belongs to Hom(v).Find basis for V for which $\phi$ has diagonal matrix D,so as this diagonal matrix,if for $\phi$ it is true:
$\phi({a_1e_1+a_2e_2+a_3c_3}) = (4a_1-a_2-2a_3)e_1 +(2a_1+a_2-2a_3)e_2+(a_1-a_2+a_3)e_3$.How should I find the basis of V made of his own vectors?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The matrix of this transformation with respect to the basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ is
$$
A = \pmatrix{
4&-1&-2\\
2&1&-2\\
1&-1&1
}
$$
perhaps you know how to find the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: Why isn't the A^t one but A?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Shoult the transported matrix $A^t$ be instead written of A because if we have for example $a_1 =-3e_1+7e_2 ,a_2=e_1-2e_2 $,then the matrix is (-3,7)(1,-2)

Comment: "Transposed", not transported.  Anyway, that is not correct (but you would get the same eigenvalues).  The example that you've written does not make sense in the notation of the problem; in this problem, $a_i$ is a scalar and $e_i$ is a vector.

Comment: Ok but on the left of this matrix we have to have the basis right?, then how should it look as an row or column?

Comment: I don't understand your statement.  I'll say this though: if we write
$$
\pmatrix{a_1\\a_2\\a_3} = a_1 e_1 + a_2 e_2 + a_3 e_3
$$
then 
$$
A \pmatrix{a_1\\a_2\\a_3} = 
T(a_1e_1 + a_2 e_2 + a_3 e_3)
$$
only if we define $A$ as I have defined it above.